# get dependencies not work my sdk version is 2.10.5

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[enter image dRunning "flutter pub get" in flutter_app...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.5.

Because flutter_app depends on flutter_signin_button >=2.0.0-nullsafety.0 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because flutter_app depends on flutter_signin_button >=2.0.0-nullsafety.0 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1escription here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7qoo.png)

how to solve this problem.

Comment: run `flutter upgrade` in your terminal, to get the latest version of dart sdk

Comment: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
  Command: git fetch --tags
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: when run the flutter upgrade it gives above message.

Comment: run `flutter doctor` and check if there are any issues

Comment: Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.
this issue found in flutter doctor

Comment: You have to install android studio and then from there install the android sdk and the android cmd line tools, then your issue will be resolved

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.